# Opensource Geocoding APIs

Tags: geocoding, api

I am in need of a geocoding api to use in my application. I tried Google maps api but it restricts 10 requests per second. The thing is place names will be there in my csv file and it should geocode for those place names in csv file. Since there are around 900 names in my csv file, only 10 were being geocoded using Google maps api.

I would like to know if using geonames or other opensource geocoding apis would be an option, with respect to number of requests per second and maximum number of requests per day.

Comment: There was a good answer on SO just a few days ago http://stackoverflow.com/a/33655184/1504487

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Nominatim](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/). Also Qgis can perform geocoding using plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Try Mapzen Search:

https://mapzen.com/projects/search

Here's a demo of a Leaflet application using the API:

http://pelias.github.io/leaflet-geocoder/#12/40.7261/-73.9806

Comment: even mapzen will give 6 requests per second.